# Insert data from text fields into SQLite database 

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, sqlite

I am trying to insert data into my SQLite database. I have imported all the neccassry frameworks and database files nedded for my project. In my controller class xib there are two textfields and a button. I want the data entered into both of the text fields saved in my database when I click on the button.

In my app delagate I have created two functions, one function to append the path of the database, and the other to insert data into the database. In the insert function, I check for certain conditions, i.e., if data gets added, an alert view should be displayed showing the record added, but when I add a new record it always goes into the `else` block, which is an error.

```
-(void)checkAndCreateDB {
    NSString* databaseName = @"login.sqlite";
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath=[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"login.sqlite"];
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
    if(success) return;
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];
}

-(void)insertData{

    sqlite3 *database;
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
     NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath=[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"login.sqlite"];
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO Loginchk (uname,password) VALUES ('%@',' %@');",Gunameq,Gpassq];
        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, nil)== SQLITE_OK)
        {
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [Gunameq UTF8String], -1, NULL);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [Gpassq UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        }

        if(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_DONE) 
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add Record" message:@"Contact Added" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];    
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            alert=nil;

        }
        else 
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"record" message:@"record not created" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];   
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            alert=nil;
        }   
        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);    
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
}
```

This is my login controller class. Here I have declared a function through which I access my app delegate's functions.

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{

    Gpassq=Password.text;
    Gunameq=Uname.text;


    NSLog(@"%@%@",Gunameq,Gpassq);
    AddListAppDelegate *appDelegate =(AddListAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    [appDelegate insertData];

}
```

Please solve this problem.

Comment: ........ possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699025/how-to-insert-data-in-sqlite-database/5699047#5699047

Comment: I closed your previous question, since this one contains much more information. However, in the future, just edit your questions to provide more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
static sqlite3_stmt *insertStmt = nil;

if(insertStmt == nil) 
{
    insertSql = "INSERT INTO Loginchk (uname,password) VALUES(?,?)";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insertSql, -1, &insertStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating insert statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

sqlite3_bind_text(insertStmt, 1, [Gunameq UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(insertStmt, 2, [Gpassq UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(insertStmt))
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
else
    NSLog("Inserted");
//Reset the add statement.
sqlite3_reset(insertStmt);
insertStmt = nil;
```

In above you can see. If you are binding data no need to have stringWithFormat. Just put question marks and than bind text.

Hope it helps.

Comment: hi jennis i tried this but it gives me error that no such table :Loginchk in fact i have table named loginchk.What may be the problem

Comment: hi jennis now my code is working properly but i have a problem when i run the code it show me in alertview that my record is getting added but when i open my database in browser and look in table ,my record is not added to my table.What to do so that my record gets added

Comment: @Jennis:  The `if(insertStmt == nil)` test makes no sense at the moment because it is always true.  Did you mean to declare it `static`?

Comment: @Rani after running application you are copying DB by checkandcreatedb function. So whatever changes you do that will have effect on that copied database. Just navigate to following path you will find one copy of your db and check in that. /Yourusername/Library/ApplicationSupport/iphone simulator/yoursimulatorversion/yourapplication/Documents. Here simulator version is that you select from xcode. There might b multiple folders if you run multiple application in that directory so you need to look out and find out your project.

Comment: @JeremyP yeah. I forgot to mention here. I have edited the code.

Answer (score 3):

this code may be run

```
-(void) insert:key1:key2:key3
    {
        databaseName= @"db3.sqlite";
        NSArray *documentPaths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDir=[documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
        databasePath=[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
        sqlite3 *database;


        if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
            NSString *stmnt=[[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"insert into login values(\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")", key1,key2,key3] autorelease];
            const char *sqlStatement = [stmnt UTF8String];
            sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;    
            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement,-1, &compiledStatement,NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                if (SQLITE_DONE!=sqlite3_step(compiledStatement))
                {
                    UIAlertView *al=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"INFO" 
                                                        message:@"Registration Fail"
                                                        delegate:self
                                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"
                                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [al show];
                    [al release];
                }

                else {
                    UIAlertView *al=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"INFO" 
                                                               message:@"Registerd"
                                                              delegate:self
                                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"
                                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [al show];
                    [al release];
                }


            }

            sqlite3_reset(compiledStatement);
        }
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
    -(IBAction)clicked:(id)sender
    {

        NSString *t1=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",txt1.text];

        NSString *t5=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",txt2.text];

        NSString *t3=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",txt3.text];

        //NSString *t2=[[NSString alloc]init];
        //NSInteger t3;
        //NSString *t3=[[NSString alloc]init];

        //t1=txt1.text;
        //t2=txt2.text;
        //t3=txt3.text;

        [self insert:t1:t5:t3];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
-(void)addItem{

//for saving the data into database

    if(addStmt == nil) {
        const char *sql = "insert into employee(name, address) Values(?, ?)";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [name UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [address UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    NSLog(@"%@",name);
    NSLog(@"%@",address);
    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    else
        //SQLite provides a method to get the last primary key inserted by using sqlite3_last_insert_rowid
        rowID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);

    //Reset the add statement.
    sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
}


+ (void) getInitialDataToDisplay:(NSString *)dbPath {

//for retrieving data from database

    InsertDataAppDelegate *appDelegate = (InsertDataAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        const char *sql = "select  name, address from employee";
        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

            while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);

                //NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
                Item *Obj = [[Item alloc]initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];
                Obj.name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 0)];
                Obj.address=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];
                Obj.isDirty = NO;
                [appDelegate.array addObject:Obj];
                [Obj release];
            }
        }
    }
    else
        sqlite3_close(database); //Even though the open call failed, close the database connection to release all the memory.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another way around for insert is

```
// Create insert statement for the address

NSString  *insertStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO ADDRESS (STREETNAME, STREETNUMBER, PERSONID) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%d\")", person.address.streetName, person.address.streetNumber, personID];

 if ( sqlite3_exec(databaseHandle, [insertStatement UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Person inserted.");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %s", error);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)sbumitbuttoncliked:(id)sender 
{

    sqlite3 *database;

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"somefile1.sqlite"];

    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {

        sqlite3_stmt *statment = nil;

        NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Insert into form1 (name,password,phoneno)values(\'%@\',\'%@\',\'%@\')",textobj1.text, textobj2.text,textobj3.text];

        NSLog(@"%@",queryString);
        const char *sql = [queryString UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statment, NULL);

        if (textobj1.text.length==0||textobj2.text.length==0||textobj3.text.length==0) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Not Registered " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil ];
            [alert show];
        }

        else if (sqlite3_step(statment) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"you have successfully registered" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil ];
            [alert show];
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statment);
    }
```